# matplotlib: how to get handles of existing twinx() axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to create a figure with two y-axes and add multiple curves to each of those axes at different points in my code (from different functions).

In a first function, I create a figure:

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from numpy import *

   # Opens new figure with two axes
   def function1():
          f = plt.figure(1)
          ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
          ax2 = ax1.twinx()  

          x = linspace(0,2*pi,100)
          ax1.plot(x,sin(x),'b')
          ax2.plot(x,1000*cos(x),'g')

   # other stuff will be shown in subplot 212...
```

Now, in a second function I want to add a curve to each of the already created axes:

```
   def function2():
          # Get handles of figure, which is already open
          f = plt.figure(1)
          ax3 = plt.subplot(211).axes  # get handle to 1st axis
          ax4 = ax3.twinx()            # get handle to 2nd axis (wrong?)

          # Add new curves
          x = linspace(0,2*pi,100)
          ax3.plot(x,sin(2*x),'m')
          ax4.plot(x,1000*cos(2*x),'r')
```

Now my problem is that the green curve added in the first code block is not anymore visible after the second block is executed (all others are).

I think the reason for this is the line

```
    ax4 = ax3.twinx()
```

in my second code block. It probably creates a new twinx() instead of returning a handle to the existing one.

How would I correctly get the handles to already existing twinx-axes in a plot?

Comment: Why not store the axes created in the first function and use them in the second, instead of trying to rederive them from the figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the cleanest way would be to create the axes outside the functions. Then you can supply whatever axes you like to the function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def function1(ax1, ax2):
    x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
    ax1.plot(x,np.sin(x),'b')
    ax2.plot(x,1000*np.cos(x),'g')

def function2(ax1, ax2):
    x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
    ax1.plot(x,np.sin(2*x),'m')
    ax2.plot(x,1000*np.cos(2*x),'r')

fig, (ax, bx) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
axtwin = ax.twinx()

function1(ax, axtwin)
function2(ax, axtwin)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use [get_shared_x_axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html#twinning) (get_shared_y_axes) to get a handle to the axes created by twinx (twiny):

```
# creat some axes
f,a = plt.subplots()

# create axes that share their x-axes
atwin = a.twinx()

# in case you don't have access to atwin anymore you can get a handle to it with
atwin_alt = a.get_shared_x_axes().get_siblings(a)[0]

atwin == atwin_alt # should be True
```